# Replace string in buffer programatically

Tags: elisp, replace

I'm writing some elisp code and would like to replace some string with some another string in a buffer. Which elisp function does that ? I did a search on documentation for the related function but all I'm getting is the interactive commands. Would love to see a sample code if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use functions `re-search-forward` and `replace-match` in a loop, or function `perform-replace`. See the Elisp manual, node [Search and Replace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html).

Sample code:

```
(while (re-search-forward "hello" nil t)
    (replace-match "world"))
```