# How can I replace outside of org-babel blocks?

Tags: org-babel, replace

I am using a command which affects the entire buffer, replacing all the ocurrences of a given expression

```
(goto-char (point-min)) (replace-string "foo" "bar")
```

Is it possible to apply a command like this only to the ocurrences outside an org-babel source block? That is, only the first `foo` on this example text should be replaced by `bar`, but not the second one:

```
* Test
testing foo

#+begin_src lisp
(setq foo 3)
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a modification of [replace string programmatically](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12136/53) to avoid replacing inside source blocks:

```
#+begin_src elisp
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "foo" nil t)
      (unless (org-in-src-block-p) (replace-match "bar"))))
#+end_src
```

You may use `search-forward` instead of `re-search-forward` which searches for regular expressions.

You may also use header arguments to [pass the strings as variables](http://orgmode.org/manual/var.html#var).

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of `org-in-src-block-p`. Thanks!